# Print list in tab noticias ionic + angular

Tags: angularjs, ionic-framework

I'm trying to learn and do at the same time application framework ionic + angular .

In the news tab does not display my list of information stored in an array.

Any help please...

Here is the code used :

This is my file app.js :

```
angular.module('starter', ['ionic'])

.run(function($ionicPlatform) {
  $ionicPlatform.ready(function() {

    if(window.cordova && window.cordova.plugins.Keyboard) {
      cordova.plugins.Keyboard.hideKeyboardAccessoryBar(true);
    }
    if(window.StatusBar) {
      StatusBar.styleDefault();
    }
  });
})

.config(function($stateProvider, $urlRouterProvider, $ionicConfigProvider){

    $ionicConfigProvider.navBar.alignTitle("center"); // centrar titulo de cada contenido de tab

    $stateProvider
        .state("app",{
            templateUrl: "templates/app.html",
            url: "/app",
            abstract: true
        })
        .state("app.noticias", {
            url: "/noticias",
            views: {
                "app-noticias":{
                    templateUrl: "templates/noticias.html",
                    controller: "noticiasCtrl"
                }
            }
        })  
        .state("app.servicios", {
            url: "/servicios",
            views: {
                "app-servicios":{
                    templateUrl: "templates/servicios.html",
                    controller: "serviciosCtrl"
                }
            }
        })

        $urlRouterProvider.otherwise("/app/noticias"); // Para cuando no encuentre nada se vaya a la pagina que se quiere mostrar por default           

})

.controller("noticiasCtrl", function($scope)
{

    var rawData = [{
      "id": "34",
      "City": "New York"
    }, {
      "id": "22",
      "City": "Las vegas"
    }, {
      "id": "44",
      "City": "Paris"
    }, {
      "id": "45",
      "City": "Lyon"
    }];
})

.controller("serviciosCtrl", function($scope)
{

})
```

noticias.html :

```
<ion-view title="Noticias">

    <ion-content ng-controller="noticiasCtrl">
          <ion-list>
            <ion-item ng-repeat="item in rawData">
                {{ item.city }}
            </ion-item>
          </ion-list>

      </ion-content>

</ion-view>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you tried $scope.rawData? instead of var? Using scope will add it to the scope of the controller and will be reachable.

Comment: You're welcome! If you haven't already I highly advise checking out the [shaping up with angular lesson](https://www.codeschool.com/courses/shaping-up-with-angular-js) on codeschool, it really helped me with this stuff when I got started.